# How to synchronize private organization's Git repositories with public GitHub?

Tags: git, github, synchronization

I have a simple question. We have an organization and have private (closed to our team members only) Git server.

We would like to have some repositories published on GitHub as organization's repositories and have them in synchronization. For instance, if some public or private member makes changes to repository (in private or public repository), I would like it to also reflect on public or private repository accordingly.

Is this possible? Are there some applications which do these synchronizations? I've looked and I couldn't find anything :(

Thank you very much.

Comment: If both the private repository and the public one are allowed to write, it would be troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need separation to avoid the risks of:

1. Something that should not be pubic becoming public; and
2. Something public that you don't want enter your private repo.

I would avoid automation, at least in the first few months.

It would be best to avoid code duplication and you could have the public code included as a NuGet dependency in your project. If you cannot / don't want to use a nuget dependency then you could have a private fork of the public repo in your private universe.

Your final setup will depend on the particular needs of your organization, e.g. do you maintain one version of multiple versions of the public code (i.e. is there a public and private version of the libraries that you share with the public?).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GitLab](https://gitlab.com) to maintain the public copy that synchronizes automatically (I don't think GitHub has such a feature). You can create a [mirror of the repository](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/repository_mirroring.html) and set it to automatically [pull changes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/repository_mirroring.html#pulling-from-a-remote-repository-starter) periodically from your private repository and keep it synchronized. However, new changes should not be pushed to this copy, as it would break the mirroring.

If you necessarily must use GitHub, a workaround could be to use a private GitLab repository as above, and then set up a [push mirror](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/repository_mirroring.html#setting-up-a-push-mirror-from-gitlab-to-github-core) from the GitLab repository to a public GitHub repository.